# Freeing Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, malloc, free

I'm having trouble figuring out what this error means exactly. It says:

```
map-test(29262,0x7fffb118e340) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fa5d7001000: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

However, I'm pretty sure that it was allocated. Here are the functions in question. I guess that it could be possible that I messed up the memory somewhere, but I don't think that's the case, but then again I'm new at some of this stuff and my professor loves pointers religiously (sadly). Can someone steer me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance.

map.cpp

```
#include "map.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

Map::Map() {
    database = new MapEntry*[DATABASE_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++){
        database[i] = new MapEntry("", 0);
    }
}

/* Adds (inserts) val with the associated key.
 * Returns if successful or not.  (It is not successful if we are out of
 * memory, or if the key already exists.)
 */
bool Map::add(const char *key, int val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++)
        if (database[i]->getVal() == 0) {
            database[i]->setVal(val);
            database[i]->setKey(key);
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

/* Searches for the key.  If found it sets ret to the correct val and
 * returns true.  Otherwise this function returns false.
 */
bool Map::get(const char *key, int &ret) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++){
        if (database[i]->getKey() == key) {
            ret = database[i]->getVal();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/* Returns the size (memory consumed) by this data structure. */
int Map::size() {
    int totalsize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++){
        if (database[i]->getVal() != 0) {
            totalsize += sizeof(database[i]);
        }
    }
    return totalsize;
}

/* Removes the current value from the Map AND frees up any memory that it can.
 * Returns true if there was something to remove, false otherwise.
 */
bool Map::remove(const char *key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++){
        if (database[i]->getKey() == key) {
            database[i]->setKey("");
            database[i]->setVal(0);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/* Returns the number of names with a given prefix.
 * EX: If we have {John, Jonathan, Paul, Mark, Luke, Joanna} then
 * howMany("Jo") == 3
 */
int Map::howMany(const char *prefix) {
    int count = 0;
    std::string beginning(prefix);
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++){
        std::string key(database[i]->getKey());
        if (key.substr(0, beginning.size()).compare(beginning) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

/* Frees all memory */
Map::~Map() {
for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++) {
        delete database[i];
    }
    delete[] database;
}
```

map.hpp

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

const int DATABASE_SIZE = 1024;

class MapEntry{
    private:
        int mIDVal;
        const char* mKeyName;

    public:
        MapEntry(const char *key, int val) {
        mKeyName = key;
        mIDVal = val;
    }
    int getVal(){
        return mIDVal;
    }
    const char* getKey(){
        return mKeyName;
    }
    void setVal(int val){
        mIDVal = val;
    }
    void const setKey(const char* key){
        mKeyName = key;
    }
};

class Map{
    public:
        Map();

        bool add(const char *key, int val);

        void print();

        bool get(const char *key, int &ret);

        int size();

        bool remove(const char *key);

        int howMany(const char *prefix);

    ~Map();
private:
    MapEntry **database;
    Map(const Map &m){
        // Copy constructor in private to avoid double deleting.
    }
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "map.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Map myMap;
    myMap.add("Philip Fry", 51798);
    myMap.add("Turanga Leela", 987651234);
    myMap.add("Philip Fry", 89715);
    int pringles = 0;
    myMap.get("Philip Fry", pringles);
    cout << pringles << "\n";
    myMap.print();
    cout << myMap.size() << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    myMap.remove("Philip Fry");
    myMap.print();
    pringles = 0;
    myMap.get("Philip Fry", pringles);
    cout << pringles << "\n";
    const char* prefix = "Phi";
    cout << myMap.howMany(prefix) << "\n";

    myMap.~Map();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: while passing key as argument to bool Map::add(const char *key, int val), Is key pointer allocated using malloc?

Comment: The error means that you have a bug in your code, somewhere, that ends up corrupting memory. Since the code you showed failed to comply with the requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], no further answer is possible, only random guesses. The most likely explanation is that your class does not comply with the Rule Of Three; however due to the lack of the aforementioned [mcve] it's only a guess.

Comment: Apologies. Edited to add detail.

Comment: Where are your copy constructor and copy assignment operators? If you have a destructor you probably need the other two as well.  Alternatively you can make them private to forbid them.  Imagine you make a copy of your `Map` object and it goes out of scope.  Do you think the default copy constructor is going to allocate new memory for you?  Do you think that the destructor is then going to attempt to de-allocate memory that was never allocated? Edit: Looks like @SamVarshavchik beat me to the punch ;-)

Comment: No, this is still far short from a [mcve]. Did you read this [help] center article, yet, and if not, why not?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm failing to see where it wasn't Minimal (I added code thinking it was too minimal for you), Complete (all of the necessary components are there to reproduce the problem as described), or Verifiable (it reproduces the problem if done). Through the commented code and the original question at the top, I believe I have filled all of the requirements. What do you think is missing that I need to add so I can comply?

Comment: @JustinRandall What do you mean by making them private to forbid them? Like just creating an empty function and putting it in private?

Comment: You are mistaken. This fails the "Complete" and "Verifiable" requirements, since it is not possible for anyone other than you to compile and reproduce your problem, from just the code that's shown. If it were complete, than I, or anyone else, can simply copy what you have, compile, and verify your problem. That, obviously, isn't true.

Comment: **`pointer being freed was not allocated`** -- is fairly descriptive, meaning you are passing something to `free` that was not previously allocated with `malloc, calloc or realloc`.

Comment: @SutterBestwick Yes just declare them in your Map.hpp as private. No need to implement since they can't be invoked.   For example `Map(const Map&); // no implementation` and
    `Map& operator=(const Map&); // no implementation`

Answer (score 0):

You are double free-ing the memory right here when you are calling the destructor directly. You are not supposed to call the destructor manually.  It is automatically called when objects go out of scope. There is your double delete.

```
myMap.~Map();  ///< this is wrong (get rid of it)
```

If you want visual evidence that the destructor is getting invoked twice, then modify it to print.

```
/* Frees all memory */
Map::~Map() {
    std::cout << "Map::~Map() invoked!" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < DATABASE_SIZE; i++) {
        delete database[i];
    }
    delete[] database;
}
```